# Waiting for all jobs to be finished with async await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to understand the usage of async-await in C#5. If I have 2 jobs started in a method, is there a best way to wait for their completion in C#5+ ? I've done the example below but I fail to see what the async await keywork brings here besides free documentation with async keyword.

I made the following example, I want "FINISHED !" to be printed last. It is not the case however. What did I miss ? How can I make the async method wait until all jobs are finished ? Is there a point using async-await here ? I could just do Task.WaitAll with a non-async method here. I don't really understand what async brings in case you want to wait.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fooWorker = new FooWorker();
        var barWorker = new BarWorker();
        var test = new Class1(fooWorker, barWorker);

        test.SomeWork();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public Foo(string bar) => Bar = bar;
    public string Bar { get; }
}

public class Class1
{
    private IEnumerable<Foo> _foos;
    private readonly FooWorker _fooWorker;
    private readonly BarWorker _barWorker;

    public Class1(FooWorker fooWorker, BarWorker barWorker)
    {
        _fooWorker = fooWorker;
        _barWorker = barWorker;
    }

    public void SomeWork()
    {
        _foos = ProduceManyFoo();
        MoreWork();

        Console.WriteLine("FINISHED !");
    } 

    private async void MoreWork()
    {
        if (_foos == null || !_foos.Any()) return;

        var fooList = _foos.ToList();

        Task fooWorkingTask = _fooWorker.Work(fooList);
        Task barWorkingTask = _barWorker.Work(fooList);

        await Task.WhenAll(fooWorkingTask, barWorkingTask);
    }

    private IEnumerable<Foo> ProduceManyFoo()
    {
        int i = 0;
        if (++i < 100) yield return new Foo(DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
}

public abstract class AWorker
{
    protected virtual void DoStuff(IEnumerable<Foo> foos)
    {
        foreach (var foo in foos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(foo.Bar);
        }
    }

    public Task Work(IEnumerable<Foo> foos) => Task.Run(() => DoStuff(foos));
}

public class FooWorker : AWorker { }
public class BarWorker : AWorker { }
```

Comment: You aren't blocking on the call to `MoreWork` in `SomeWork`, so it proceeds directly to the `Console.WriteLine` while the task executes in the background.

Comment: Never use `async void` (except for event handlers and only there because these can only return void) and instead let `MoreWork` return a Task which you can then await. Also it’s async all the way up – thus `SomeWork` and then `Main` need to be async too and return Tasks.

Comment: @Baguette: I recommend reading [`async` best practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx); it includes guidelines such as "avoid `async void`" and "async all the way".

Answer (score 0):

You are firing off tasks and just forgetting them, while the thread continues running.  This fixes it.

Main:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var fooWorker = new FooWorker();
    var barWorker = new BarWorker();
    var test = new Class1(fooWorker, barWorker);
    await test.SomeWork();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

SomeWork:

```
public async Task SomeWork()
{
    _foos = ProduceManyFoo();
    await MoreWork();
    Console.WriteLine("FINISHED !");
}
```

MoreWork signature change:

```
private async Task MoreWork()
```

The obvious code smell which should help make the problem clear is using `async void`.  Unless required this should always be avoided.

When using `async` and `await` you'll usually want to chain the `await` calls to the top-level (in this case `Main`).

`await` is non-blocking, so anything that calls an `async` method should really care about the `Task` being returned.

Comment: I followed your guidelines, though I couldn't make Main method async, and it seems the dates appear consistently before the FINISHED !

I decided to go further and called await Class1.SomeWork() into an async method of an IDisposable class. I have an issue howeve. Object disposal happened randomly before or after the other output to console.